# Update activity by notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I know use PendingIntent can open a activity,
but my question is if the activity which I want to  open is 
already in show,how to update this activity？

Comment: just show an alert dialog with notification message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are exactly searching for, but look at this

[Android update activity UI from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695537/android-update-activity-ui-from-service)

and this

[Update view from different thread Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277608/update-view-from-different-thread-android)

Every activity UI update from another application should be done by intent mechanism